# I'm doing python course on mooc.fi but im stuck on "Food expidenture"

Tags: python

```
# Write your solution here
times = int(input("How many times a week do you eat at the student cafeteria? "))
price = float(input("The price of a typical student lunch? "))
groc = float(input("How much money do you spend on groceries in a week? "))

print("Average food expenditure:")
print (f"Daily: {times * price + groc / 7} ")
```

puts out:

```
How many times a week do you eat at the student cafeteria? 4
The price of a typical student lunch? 2.5
How much money do you spend on groceries in a week? 28.5
Average food expenditure:
Daily: 14.071428571428571 I need it to be 5.5 not 14.07
```

Pls can anyone help out must be piece of cake for a pro XD

also need weekly output of 38.5. but i dont know what im doing wrong i think i must prioritize the math but idk how to do it.

Comment: Just like when doing math, you can wrap expressions in `()` to have certain parts evaluate first.

Comment: yeah i justt realized with () u can control it. I fixed it myself. Thanks for the help mate i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You have a *precedence* problem.

In arithmetic expressions, multiplication and division happen before addition. So this:

```
times * price + groc / 7
```

divides `groc` by 7 and then adds it to the result of multiplying `times` by `price`. You want instead to divide the whole value `tiems * price + groc` by 7, which means you need parentheses:

```
(times * price + groc) / 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the daily output just use parentheses.
Like simple math, `((times*price)+groc)/7`
and I'm pretty sure this will do.

As for the weekly if I'm getting this right, just do this,
`weekly = (daily * 7)`
again, if you are doing this directly use parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
cafeteria = float(input("How many times a week do you eat at the student ""
cafeteria? "))
price = float(input("The price of a typical student lunch? "))
money = float(input("How much money do you spend on groceries in a week? "))
spent = money + (cafeteria * price)
 
print("Average food expenditure:\n")
print("Daily:", spent / 7, "euros")
print("Weekly:", spent, "euros")
```

this was my solution in that course.